# What config file am I missing, and how do I find or generate it?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

I am trying to run the Microsoft Enterprise Assistant Bot Template, using the Bot Framework Composer.
I've followed the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/templates/enterprise-assistant-tutorial).

However when I try to run the bot(s) locally, only the two skill bots are able to start, and the root bot throws the following error:

> Sorry, something went wrong with publishing. Try again or exit out of this task.

> Error: [2021-07-29T10:56:43+0100]:Invalid or non-existent JSON config file - 2: cannot LoadConfig() with config_or_path=C:\Users\pdobosi\AppData\Roaming\BotFrameworkComposer\models\pretrained.20200924.microsoft.dte.00.06.en, config.is_discarded()=0, config_folder="C:\Users\pdobosi\AppData\Roaming\BotFrameworkComposer\models\pretrained.20200924.microsoft.dte.00.06.en", config_file="C:\Users\pdobosi\AppData\Roaming\BotFrameworkComposer\models\pretrained.20200924.microsoft.dte.00.06.en\config.json", fs::exists(config_or_path)=1, fs::is_directory(config_or_path)=1, fs::is_regular_file(config_or_path)=0, fs::exists(config_file)=0, FILE=D:\a\1\s\oc\Model.cc, FUNC=operator (), LINE=1809

I've checked the path described in the error and it's an empty folder, so my config.json file is missing.
From what I could gather it's the config file of the [orchestrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-orchestrator)'s pretrained model. However I couldn't find any way to either generate or simply copy it.
How do I provide this file? Am I even supposed to, as this isn't mentioned anywhere in the guide, or is this a possible bug?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried doing this command?

```
mkdir generated
bf orchestrator:create --hierarchical --in ./CognitiveModels --out ./generated --model ./model
```

From [this MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-orchestrator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs#create-the-orchestrator-snapshot-file)